# How can I return a useRef variable, defined before, from a function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm rendering a list. On specific buttons I want to have a ref. Is there a way to archive that? Or any workarounds?

```
const plusParent = useRef(null);
const plusChild = useRef(null);
const minusParent = useRef(null);
const minusChild = useRef(null);

const detectRef = (button, comp) => {
    switch (button) {
      case '+':
        return comp === 'parent' ? plusParent : plusChild;
      case '-':
        return comp === 'parent' ? minusParent : minusChild;
    }
  };

{row.map((button) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                 ref={() => detectRef(button, 'parent')}
                >
                <Text>{button}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
```

If I try to access one of my useRef Variables I'm getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `ref` ends up to be an **anonymous arrow function**. Just remove that additional function wrapper and directly invoke the function to return the result.

```
{row.map((button) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                 ref={detectRef(button, 'parent')}
                >
                <Text>{button}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's still not working :/ If I just write ref= {plusParent} its working

Comment: Then check your comparisons by logging the values.